# Translate a string using a character map

Tags: python, puzzle

Consider the following pattern

A → D
M → P
X → A
a → d
m → p
x → a

I need to write a program to solve the following message

Vrphwklqjphdqlqjixo

If there is any inbuilt function in python please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not a map, it is a rotation: http://theblob.org/rot.cgi?text=Vrphwklqjphdqlqjixo

Comment: @Selcuk I see that now, but what are the arrows for?

Comment: @cricket_007 From one point of view every rotation is a map, but here you can only see a subset of the map for you to exptrapolate the general pattern, which is a ROT-23 scheme. Not every letter in the encrypted text can be found in the sample mappings.

Comment: I understand question is of very low but why every one is down rated it ?

Comment: @rajdamani I didn't downvote you but your question is off topic because you are not asking a question but expecting us to do your homework for you.

Comment: @Selcuk Yeah, I see it now. I thought the uppercase and lowercase letters "mapped" differently.

Comment: @selcuk i not asking a code, please help me in suggesting any function !

Comment: I don't think he's looking for code, just pointers towards any built-in functions within the language. It's a reasonable question for someone new to a language.

Comment: @BingsF I disagree and this is a discussion more suitable for Meta but still upvoted your answer as it is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in function you seem to be looking for is str.translate:

```
S.translate(table [,deletechars]) -> string
```

> Return a copy of the string S, where all characters occurring in the optional argument deletechars are removed, and the remaining characters have been mapped through the given translation table, which must be a string of length 256 or None.
>      If the table argument is None, no translation is applied and the operation simply removes the characters in deletechars.

Alternatively, if you are using a rotation scheme, you may find the `chr` and `ord` functions useful:

```
chr(i) -> character
```

> Return a string of one character with ordinal i; 0 <= i < 256.

```
ord(c) -> integer
```

> Return the integer ordinal of a one-character string.